# TypeScript IntelliSense not working as expected in VS2012

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, typescript, intellisense

I am playing with typescript and for some reason the intellisense does not work on Visual Studio 2012. Anyways take a look at this example: **[LINK](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=%0A//%20--------------------%20Example%201%20----------------------------%0Afunction%20Class1%28%29%20%7B%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20this.Foo%20=%20%22%22;%20%20%20%20%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20c%20=%20new%20Class1%28%29;%0Ac.Foo%20=%20%22Blabla%22;%20//%20intellisense%20works!%0A%0A%0A%0A//%20--------------------%20Example%202%20----------------------------%0Aclass%20Class2%7B%0A%09Foo:string;%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20myArray%20=%20new%20Class2%5B16%5D;%0AmyArray%5B0%5D.Foo%20=%20%22someString%22;%20//%20intellicense%20works%0A)**

When I try to run that same exact example in VS2013 I do not get intellsense on the lines that I comment. Is this a bug? I have version 0.9.1.1

In other words note how when I press `.` I do not get intellisense:
[image]

In typescript website I will do get intellisense http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/

P.S.

why down vote without even saying why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myArray = new Class2[16];
```

This line does not create an array of size 16. It tries to invoke the `new` operator on the member called "16" of `Class2`, which is of type `any`. If you want an array, write something like

```
var myArray: Class2[] = [];
```